# Internet Explorer não reconhece classes do CSS que funcionam corretamente em outros navegadores

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

O site que desenvolvi no WordPress não abre corretamente no Internet Explorer. Percebi que o Internet Explorer não está encontrando os estilos corretamente.

Site: http://nakbrasil.com.br/novo

Comment: Dê uma olhada nas linhas 254 e 259, no seu CSS inline, parece que você não fechou as chaves de `@media`.

Comment: Humm.. vou analisar... ams será que pode ser isso que o IE não reconhece o caminho dos estilos?

Comment: Perfeitooo @Molx! Muito obrigado pela dica :))

Comment: Encontrei um problema parecido em que um erro no CSS causava problemas apenas no IE, mas não no firefox, no [SO em inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974018/css-style-not-recognized-in-ie9).

Comment: Já está na hora de o IE aposentar de vez kkk meu.. ele é o único que atrasa nossa vida!! Obrigadão mesmo (Y)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O IE não consegue lidar tão bem com erros no CSS quanto os outros navegadores. No seu código, duas chaves `}` estão faltando nos itens `@media`, de forma que os estilos depois deste erro não são lidos corretamente. Isso pode acontecer para outros tipos de erros também, como uma classe com nome reservado, como [nesse caso do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974018/css-style-not-recognized-in-ie9).

Procurar erros manualmente em centenas de linhas de CSS não é simples, por isso uma boa ideia é usar sites como [CSS LINT](http://csslint.net/) em que você cola seu CSS e ele procura problemas no código, e então tentar resolver o primeiro erro (outros erros provavelmente serão detectados como consequência do primeiro).